# Reading line 3 to 5 from file, how do I make those line numbers into variables?

Tags: perl

I am super new to perl but I am simply trying to open a file and reading some lines from it.

The code so far looks like this:

```
open FILE, "file.txt" or die "can not open file"; 
while (<FILE>) { 
  print if ($.== 3..5)
}
```

But I need to be able to change what lines to get. So those 3 and 5 numbers need to be variables.

Also can someone help me understand this code better? I'm wondering what $. is exactly and how would I replace the print command with putting it into an array or something to work further with those lines?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful with the syntax. Running your example through `perl -MO=Deparse,-p` shows that perl interprets it as

```
(open(FILE, 'file.txt') or die('can not open file'));
while (defined(($_ = <FILE>))) {
((($. == 3) .. 5) and print($_));
```

Just by luck, the range operator does what you hope it to do because `..` uses `$.` (input line number) by default.

To use variables instead of constants, just use

```
print if $. == $x .. $. == $y;
```

Comment: Interesting, now it only prints 1 line of the file each time. Determined by the $start variable and the $end doesn't seem to matter. I am using strawberry perl. EDIT: wait this was for the other guy that answered. Was that you? I don't know but that answer is gone.

Comment: There was an error in the other reply, so the author removed it.

Comment: The syntax `print if $. ~~ [3 .. 5];` would also be interesting (and elegant!), although probably somewhat inefficient on very large ranges.

Comment: @choroba But hey if you care to listen. What I'm trying to do now with those lines is to put them into 4 arrays. The first number in each line goes to array 1, second to array 2, third to 3 and fourth to array 4. The lines will be about 25 actually. And the 4 numbers in each line are split with commas. I'll figure it out eventually but its a bit hard learning programming and having to do what I find the most confusing part right at start. After this all I have to do is just endless math. That should be simple.

Comment: @choroba How do I put these lines into something so I can then work with them. Instead of just printing? I want to be able to work with them so I can then split them and put into 4 arrays like I said above.

Comment: @user1463899: You can use `push` to add something to an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -E'say for "aa".."ah"' | perl -ne'print if 3..5'
```

Using `$.` is unnecessary when you use constants according to [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) but when you use variables you ave to mention it explicitly:

```
perl -E'say for "aa".."ah"' | perl -ne'BEGIN{($f,$t) = splice@ARGV,0,2;}print if ($.==$f)..($.==$t)' 3 5
```